# Syntax for groovy to duplicate PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, groovy

I'm trying to duplicate the PowerShell `Invoke-RestMethod` to something similar in Groovy (groovy is standard we use in our coded pipeline).

I've done a lot of searching without success. I was wondering if I can get some help or suggestions on a possible alternative if there isn't a similar call?

The 3 three lines of PowerShell I'm trying to duplicate in Groovy are:

```
$tokenrequest = @{ "grant_type" = "password"; "username" = "adminuser"; "password" = "adminpassword" }
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://abcd.com/executionmanager/api/Token" -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Headers @{ Authorization = ("OAuth2")} -Method POST -Body $tokenrequest
$token = $token.access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of libraries to do that

the following one quite unknown

```groovy
//download dependency from maven repository
@Grab(group='acme.groovy', module='acmehttp', version='20180403')
import groovyx.acme.net.AcmeHTTP

def ctx = AcmeHTTP.post(
    url:   "https://httpbin.org/post", //the url could be used for tests 
    //define body as map as soon as we are sending it as www-form
    body: [ "grant_type": "password", "username": "adminuser", "password": "adminpassword" ],
    headers:[
        "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "OAuth2"
    ],
)
assert ctx.response.code==200
//the url https://httpbin.org/post always returns json
assert ctx.response.contentType =~ "/json"
assert ctx.response.body instanceof Map

println ctx.response.body
//i guess your token should be accessible like this:
//println ctx.response.body.access_token
```

Comment: Thanks @daggett, this definitely has promise.  I was also asked to use Ansible instead of Groovy.  So I'm working on the yaml now.